# REGEXEXTRACT formula that can pull first and last name from a full name while excluding middle initial and suffix?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet with full names in one column in the following format:

- Kim J. Barry
- John B. Grant Jr
- Valerie Johnson
- John Z. Smith III
- Che'Yenne L. James-Fried
- Ryan M. Ze'O

I am trying to split the names so that the first name is split in one column and the last name is split in another column. I want to exclude the middle initial and the suffix. However, not all names have a middle initial and suffix, and some have a special character in the name. I've created [this Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19qWNexDZLtzbuPG0sLSkJzafFkRWOdcL3xiSKqEUjgI/edit?usp=sharing) for reference.

Is there a way to do this via REGEX or another formula within Google Sheets?

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| Kim | Barry |
| John | Grant |
| Valerie | Johnson |
| John | Smith |
| Che'Yenne | James-Fried |
| Ryan | Ze'O |

I've tried using REGEXEXTRACT and various other formulas, but either the middle initial is retained with the first name or the suffix gets extracted with or without the last name.

The below formula is the closest I've gotten to split the first name and last name:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"^(.+?)([^\s,]+)((?:[JS]r\.?|III?|IV))?$")`

But it gives me this result:

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| Kim J. | Barry |
| John B. Grant | Jr |
| Valerie | Johnson |
| John Z. Smith | III |
| Che'Yenne L. | James-Fried |
| Ryan M. | Ze'O |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(ifna(regexextract(A2:A,"(\S+)\s?.*?,\s(\S+)")))
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Is there a way to adjust the formula so that the first and last names switch columns? It's preferred cell B2 has Kim under First Name and cell C2 has Barry under Last Name. Thank you again!

Comment: You can try: `=query(index(ifna(regexextract(A2:A,"(\S+)\s?.*?,\s(\S+)"))),"Select Col2, Col1")`

Comment: I tried this: `=query(index(ifna(regexextract(A2:A,"(\S+)\s?.*?,\s(\S+)")))A2:A,"select C, B")` , but it gives me an error. However, the original answer you provided me works for the sheet I'm currently working in so I will use that. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You could use two splits, one for the comma to divide last name and first name; and then another by the space to divide two names or two last names. With INDEX(...,1) you'll be able to only grab the first in each case; and BYROW and BYCOL you'd be able to repeat the process in the array:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(f,IFERROR(
BYCOL(SPLIT(f,", ",0),LAMBDA(n,INDEX(SPLIT(n," "),1))))))
```

[image]